# Switch between browser tabs using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-tab

I need to switch between the browser tabs, used the following code,

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"\t");
```

It was working properly sometimes only, but sometimes it is showing an exception.
Can anyone suggest me is there any other instructions for switching tabs within a single window by using java.

Comment: When it is throwing errors and what exception you're getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [switch tabs using selenium Webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Iam geting the following exception : Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use window handle function here. Here is a sample working code in java:

```
    String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); // get the current window handle
    System.out.println(parentHandle);               //Prints the parent window handle 
    String anchorURL = anchor.getAttribute("href"); //Assuming u are clicking on a link which opens a new browser window
    anchor.click();                                 //Clicking on this window
    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) { //Gets the new window handle
        System.out.println(winHandle);
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);        // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)              
    }
//Now your driver works on the current new handle
//Do some work here.....
//Time to go back to parent window
    driver.close();                                 // close newly opened window when done with it
    driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);         // switch back to the original window
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Switching between browser window is different from switching b/w tabs.

In some browser windowhandler command may work but it wont work in all browser.

Here is the solution to navigate b/w tabs

for navigating left to right side:

```
Actions action= new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
```

For navigating right to left :

```
Actions action= new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following code is working fine-

```
String oldTab=driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.findElement(pageObj.getL_Popup_Window()).click();
     ArrayList<String> newTab = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        newTab.remove(oldTab);
        driver.switchTo().window(newTab.get(0));
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(pageObj.getI_input_name());
    ele.click();
    ele.sendKeys(name);
    driver.findElement(pageObj.getI_submit()).click();
    driver.switchTo().window(oldTab);
```