# How to work on opened page after opening it on new tab using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am able to switch on another tab at same browser but after opening that page, on another tab I am not able to perform the operation.

**Current scenario held on:**

1. Give credential and login the account.
2. Click on email address or username through this it open a frame.
3. From that frame click on "Add account" button.
4. After click on "Add account" button I am successfully open the link on another tab.
5. After opening tab, I am able to switch on that window.

But after switch on that window I want to give credential again on login page, but don't want to close the first opened tab on which account is loggedIn.

I am doing it in framework so please check the below code and according to this integrate your code and help me.

```
private boolean operateWebDriver(String operation, String Locator,
            String value, String objectName) throws Exception {
        boolean testCaseStep = false;

        try {
            System.out.println("Operation execution in progress");
            WebElement temp = getElement(Locator, objectName);
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("SendKey")) {
                temp.sendKeys(value);
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click")) {
                temp.click();

            }
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("newTab")) {
                System.out.println("newTab" + temp);
                Actions newTab = new Actions(driver);
                newTab.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(temp).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
               newTab.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.TAB)).perform();
            }
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Verify")) {
                System.out.println("Verify--->" + temp);
                temp.isDisplayed();
            }

            testCaseStep = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred operateWebDriver"
                    + e.getMessage());

            //Taking snapshot when test case fail.

            System.out.println("Taking snapshot");

            File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);  
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("E:\\workspace for selenium\\AutomationFramework\\AutomationFramework\\Screenshots\\screenshot.jpg"));

        }

        return testCaseStep;
    }

    public WebElement getElement(String locator, String objectName)
            throws Exception {
        WebElement temp = null;
        System.out.println("Locator-->" + locator);
        if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.id(objectName));

        } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("xpath")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath(objectName));
            System.out.println("xpath temp ----->" + temp);
        } else if (locator.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            temp = driver.findElement(By.name(objectName));
            System.out.println("name temp ----->" + temp);
        } 
        return temp;

    }


}
```

Comment: Where you want to continue, means on Main window or on newly opened window?

Comment: @SarithaG I want to work on same window but on different tab, like after opening a link on new tab my test operation should work on it.

Comment: Try following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Yah..Use that link. That will work.

Answer (score 0):

Now I am able to work on opened URL after opening it on another tab. Here is the code which is working from my end.

```
private boolean operateWebDriver(String operation, String Locator,
            String value, String objectName) throws Exception {
        boolean testCaseStep = false;

        try {
            System.out.println("Operation execution in progress");
            WebElement temp = getElement(Locator, objectName);
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("SendKey")) {
                temp.sendKeys(value);
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click")) {
                temp.click();

            }
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("newTab")) {
                System.out.println("newTab" + temp);

                // Open link in new tab.
                Actions newTab = new Actions(driver);
                newTab.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(temp).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();

               //After Opening link in new tab display that window.
                newTab.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.TAB)).perform();

               // Get the number of tab opened in browser.
                ArrayList<String> newTab1 = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
                // change focus to new tab
                driver.switchTo().window(newTab1.get(0));

                // Now perform the operation here.
                if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("SendKey")) {
                    temp.sendKeys(value);
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Click")) {
                    temp.click();

                }

            }
            if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("Verify")) {
                System.out.println("Verify--->" + temp);
                temp.isDisplayed();
            }

            testCaseStep = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred operateWebDriver"
                    + e.getMessage());

            //Taking snapshot when test case fail.

            System.out.println("Taking snapshot");

            File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);  
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("E:\\workspace for selenium\\AutomationFramework\\AutomationFramework\\Screenshots\\screenshot.jpg"));

        }

        return testCaseStep;
    }
```

Comment: Glad you got something that works for you, but you're getting lucky using the first value in the list returned by `getWindowHandles()`. There is no guaranteed order to window handles. Adding logic to find the right window handle is left as an exercise to the reader; example code is available at many, many places throughout the web.

Comment: @JimEvans Thanks for your feedback, can you please provide me the reference URL of it?

Comment: How many window handles do you get, you are saying new page is opened in a new tab, if it is a tab then there will be only 1 window handle right?

Comment: @skumar Yes, currently it handle only 1 window.

Answer (score 0):

which browser are you working on? firefox doesn't work on tab.
try using chrome.. store current window handles and click the desired link to open new tab

```
//current window - before opening link on new tab    
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();  
  //write code to open new link
    tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());

        for( int k= 0 ; k< tabs2.size(); k++  ){
                for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
             driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(k));

            }
```