# How can I take a browser's control to a newly opened tab using Java in WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
//Go to a page where link is present 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='LftNav']/ul/li[3]/div/ul/li[3]/a/label"))).click();
//Click this link will open up a new tab.     
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[2]/td[9]/a")).click();

//Now I have to verify a value present in the New Tab.
```

For that I have to pass the Control to the New Tab. How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch tab (and complete windows) by using following function:

```
ArrayList<String> windowHandles = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(windowHandles.get(1));
```

exept you have only two handles. If you want to close the tab and go back you can use:

```
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(windowHandles.get(0));
```

If you have more then two tabs you can use:

```
driver.getWindowHandles().size()
```

to get the amount of opened tabs and just jump to `size()-1`

Comment: Thanks for that answer. But I have a problem now. Actually the tab which has been opened is a pdf which containing data. If the pdf contains no data then am able to verify a text present in the page, but if the pdf page contains some data. Then It is not able to verify that text. Can you please give me a suggestion.

Comment: If data is present in the pdf page then the windowhandles option is not working. It is not taking the control to the next page. I checked it but taking the control next tab.

Comment: Difficult to say because I haven't worked with PDF files and selenium yet. Actually I don't know if it is even possible to check a PDF file with selenium methods. I just found this: http://blog.wedoqa.com/2014/09/how-to-read-text-from-pdf-file-using-java-and-selenium-webdriver/

Answer (score 0):

```
String mainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle(); // get the main window handle
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//*[#id='someId']")).click(); // click some link that opens a new window

for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
 // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle (that's your newly opened window)
if(driver.findElement(By.Id("SomeID")).getText().equals("expected window title"))
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SendKeys didn't work for me. i tried following code which worked for me:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);  
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
Thread.sleep(3000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);  
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
int tabNo = driver.getWindowHandles().size();
System.out.println(tabNo);
ArrayList<String> windowHandles = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(windowHandles.get(tabNo-1)); 
driver.get("http://www.bing.com/");
```