# Does saucelabs support multiple driver in one test

Tags: saucelabs

I want to test concurrent access, so I need a test to write tests with 2 clients (aka driver in selenium). Does saucelabs support multiple driver in one test ?

If yes, which one will be display on video and screenshot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *SauceLabs* support gave me the response :

> Unfortunately, it would not be possible to run two instances of
>   RemoteWebDriver on a single test. I am not sure if this would help in
>   what you are trying to accomplish, but perhaps switching browser tabs
>   in your test might be useful. Here is a Stack Overflow link I found
>   that may be helpful:
>   [switch tabs using Selenium WebDriver with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver)