# Switch between tabs in Mozilla using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Selenium with Java, and I am using this code to switch between tabs in Mozilla, but it is opening a new window instead of a new tab. How do solve this, or is there another way to switch between tabs?

```
WebDriver shiva=new FirefoxDriver();
shiva.manage().window().maximize();
shiva.get("http://www.naukri.com/");
Thread.sleep(3000);
shiva.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/ul[1]/li[2]/a")).click(); 
shiva.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/ul[1]/li[1]/a")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"\t");
```

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

In a normal firefox window, a new window is opened in a new tab, if you go to `settings --> General --> Tabs` you will see an option `Open new window in new tab instead` [image]

But when Selenium Webdriver launches a firefox profile, this option isn't selected by default so it opens in a new window instead of a new tab.

[image]

If you want to open a new tab, you need to create a different `firefox profile` with this option enabled and then you can launch the created profile

There is another way by which you can switch to a different tab.

```
Set<String> listOfTabs = driver.getWindowHandles();
// This code will return a set with all the window ids
// Then you can switch on any of the window.
driver.switchTo.window("String Id of window");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>(webDriver.getWindowHandles());
webDriver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); // id of the tab
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be below for switching between Tabs: Assert the relevant tab based on pageTitle (I Guess)

```
shiva.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/ul[1]/li[1]/a")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

If you wish to switch between windows then use

```
driver.switchto().window(windowhandle);
```

Also I wonder how are you able to open multiple Tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Use firefox version 80.0 or above

I think it is a bug and it is resolved in firefox 80.0

I too had the same issue(using firefox version- 78.0 back then) but once i changed the version to 80 or above,it worked flawlessly