# Can we open a link in new tab (not a new window)in selenium and give commands for carrying out tasks

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can we open a link in new tab (not a new window) and give commands for carrying out tasks

And is it possible to force selenium to open it in new tab.(just like we do Right click - open in new tab)

and then how to handle the tabs

Comment: Yeah there is a concept of Windows Handlers.
Refer this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java

Answer (score 4):

Selenium does not provide a native way to open a new tab. How ever you can use workarounds. Every browser has some short cut for opening new tabs.You can use sendskeys method to do that.

Try the following code:

```
 WebDriver DRIVER=new FirefoxDriver();
            DRIVER.get("http://google.com");
            WebElement El1=DRIVER.findElement(By.xpath("//body"));
            El1.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL,"t");
DRIVER.get("http://google.com");
```

Comment: Note that it is `COMMAND + T` on osx.

Answer (score 1):

```
Selenium Supports Mouse Hover actions and Right Click functionality, where user can right click on link and choose to open in new Tab.

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(URL);
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
WebElement linkpath = driver.Findelement(by.xpath(path of the link));
act.contextclick(linkpath).perform();  // right click
act.sendkeys("T").perform(); // click on new tab
```

Comment: this just opens the right click menu options, doesn't select open in new tab option