# Handle TABs in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to switch between two tabs and found following code

```
 ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (page.getWindowHandles());
     System.out.println(tabs2.size());
        page.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
        page.close();
        page.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(0));
```

I have one doubt in this. My window is same so `page.getWindowHandles()` is returning only one handle. `tabs2.size` is 1 so `page.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));` is giving exception `ArrayIndexOutOfBound`

I found similar code in this post [switch tabs using Selenium WebDriver with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java) but for me this code is giving exception.

Comment: whats the issue here? If you have only 1 tab you are already there on that tab ... and `tabs2.size()` is returning `1` that is correct.

Comment: I opened two tabs then I am using this code still it's returning 1. then how to work on two tabs?

Comment: do you open second tab using `selenium` or manually or it is application behavior?

Comment: I used this code page.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");

Answer (score 0):

Just try and add a line of code to ensure there are two or more tabs open in the browser :

```
page.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
```

> Note that the actual keys to send depend on your OS, for example, Mac
>   uses `Keys.COMMAND + t`, instead of `Keys.CONTROL + t`.

Post this, the piece of code used by you seems appropriate to switch tabs :

```
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (page.getWindowHandles());
System.out.println(tabs2.size());
page.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
page.close();
page.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(0));
```

***Note*** : I am assuming the **page** here is the WebDriver instance itself.

Comment: Yes thanks dear, I am new to stackoverflow so next time wont make this mistake. I am opening new tab in firefox and my code is specific to firefox only

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void switchTabsUsingPartOfUrl(String platform) {
        String currentHandle = null;
        try {
            final Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
            if (handles.size() > 1) {
                currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
            }
            if (currentHandle != null) {
                for (final String handle : handles) {
                    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
                    if (currentUrl().contains(platform) && !currentHandle.equals(handle)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (final String handle : handles) {
                    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
                    if (currentUrl().contains(platform)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Switching tabs failed");
        }
    }
```

Call this method and pass parameter a substring of url of the tab you want to switch to