# Selenium 3: Switching between the tabs

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The code that worked with Selenium 2 stopped working with Selenium 3.

This code does not work any more neither in Chrome nor in Firefox.

```
driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/windows");
String firstWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click Here")).click();
driver.switchTo().window(firstWindow);
```

I found that for Firefox there is a workaround:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

However, nothing works for Chrome.
Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [switch tabs using Selenium WebDriver with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Comment: Can you provide an exception? What exactly "does not work anymore"?

Comment: To jainish. If you look at the link you've provided, it used the code that does not work with Selenium 3 as I pointed out.

Comment: To Robert G.  There is no exception. You just stay in the second tab and do not switch to the first tab in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are indeed suffering from a new bug (or maybe intended behaviour?).

After checking out your code and testing it, I noticed that even though a new tab gets opened and focused in Chrome the `driver` does not automatically switch to that tab.

You have to add `.switchTo().window(secondWindow)` so your `driver` switches to the new (and active) tab.

So `.switchTo()` doesn't focus the tab, which the `driver` is using and thus it looks like you just stay in the second tab, even though the `driver` itself switched back to the first window.

Here is some code that might help you understand the issue:

```
    driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/windows");
    String firstWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    System.out.print("First windowhandle: " + firstWindow + "\n");

    System.out.print("Clicking on 'Click Here' \n");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click Here")).click();

    Set<String> stringSet = driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.out.print("All windowhandles: " + stringSet + "\n");
    List<String> handles = new ArrayList<>(stringSet);

    System.out.print("Switching to new window \n");
    driver.switchTo().window(handles.get(1));
    //wait for Title to change to second tab title
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("New Window"));

    System.out.print("Second (and current) windowhandle: " + driver.getWindowHandle() + "\n");

    System.out.print("Switching back to first Window. \n");
    driver.switchTo().window(firstWindow);

    //wait for Title to change back to first title
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("The Internet"));

    System.out.print("Last used windowhandle: " + driver.getWindowHandle() + "\n");
```

If you run this code you will notice two things:
a) the `driver` will switch to the correct tab (see the `WindowHandle` output)
b) the currently used tab the `driver` uses will not be properly focused in Chrome

This does seem to be a bug.

Comment: Thank you, Robert for response. I did the same investigation as in your code snippet before posting my question.   This is a bug! Who will fix it? :-) Selenium 3 is really buggy.  For example, Firefox driver did not implement the Actions class.