# New Tab does not open the new url in Firefox using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The part of the code which opens a new tab and opens a url in that new tab does not work. It opens the new tab but opens the new url in the previous tab itself. Can anyone help?

```
public class PractiseSession1 
{
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String URL="http://www.google.com";

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Sourav Mukherjee\\BP-Oyster\\S2\\Selenium Server\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
    WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
    driver.get(URL);

    //Open a url in a new tab
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+ "t");
    driver.get("http://facebook.com/");


}
}
```

Comment: The focus is still on previous tab. Try to refresh the page. driver.manage().navigate().refresh();

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: The question isn't about moving to the new tab, but directly opening a link in the tab**

You must move the driver to the new tab. To do this, you use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java):

```
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(0));
```

Comment: Ctrl + tab - I never knew this shortcut existed. Thank you.

Comment: @DonnachaConnolly And `ctrl+shift+tab` to go backwards in the tabs (just like with `alt+tab`) ;)

Comment: It still does not work, it does the same thing again.

Comment: @ThugMeister22 Did you refresh the driver as Ankur said in his comment?

Comment: @ThugMeister22 You should use `driver.switchTo().window(windowName);`. I'll get a working example and update my answer.

Comment: @ThugMeister22 I misunderstood your question. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

To open an URL then again to open a second URL in another tab you can use `JavascriptExecutor`. Here is your own code which opens `http://www.google.com` in one tab and next opens `http://facebook.com/` in another tab:

```
    String URL="http://www.google.com";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
    WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
    driver.get(URL);
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('http://facebook.com/');");
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Be careful as if the user uses a popup blocker, the script won't work.

Comment: @Nathan Pop-up blocker wouldn't stand between JavascriptExecutor and any website. Thanks