# Switch between tabs in Webdriver IO

Tags: tabs, webdriver, switch-statement

When I click on a button in my current tab, it is redirected to a new tab. I need to perform some action in the new tab and then return to the parent tab. How can this be handled using Selenium Webdriver IO?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [switch tabs using Selenium WebDriver with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like webdriver-io has this resolved with `switchTab`. Here is the API documentation: [switchTab](http://webdriver.io/api/window/switchTab.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iterator to iterate among the windows.
Example code:

```
Set <String> ids = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator <String> it = ids.iterator();
String currentWindow = it.next();
String newWindow = it.next();
```

If you want to automate on the new window, then you can switch to the new window by:

```
driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
```

Do your executions after this. Now if you want to get back to the oldWindow,

```
driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
```