# open new tab(not link in new tab) in Chrome and focus on it Selenium java

Tags: java, macos, selenium-webdriver, tabs

I have the following problem: When I run my code I want to open new tab(not link in new tab) but after I open it I can't focus on it. The focus is still on the old one.
Here is my code:

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("url for the initial tab");

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);


    // Open tab for email generation
    String url = "url for tab 2";

    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open(arguments[0])", url);

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    String site = driver.getCurrentUrl();



    if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath here")).size() != 0){
        System.out.println("Element is Present");
        }else{
        System.out.println("Element is Absent");
        }
    System.out.println("Current URL:" + site); //I get the initial url.
```

Also after I focus on the new tab how to switch to the old one?
Thanks

Comment: On my phone at the moment, but this should solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944233

Comment: @EvilFeline thanks, this was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

I have used your own code and rewritten it with a few tweaks to work with the **`WindowHandles`** using **`Set`** from **`java.util`**. Now your code opens `https://google.com` first, prints the `Page Title`, then opens the URL `https://www.facebook.com/` in a new tab shifts its focus to the new tab with the URL `https://www.facebook.com/`, prints the `Page Title` and the current URL:

```
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    public class Q44970997_newTabURL 
    {

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {

            String site = null;
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://google.com");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
            String first_tab = driver.getWindowHandle();
            String url = "https://www.facebook.com/";
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open(arguments[0])", url);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            site = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            Set<String> tab_handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
            Iterator<String> itr = tab_handles.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext())
            {
            String next_tab = itr.next();
            if(!first_tab.equalsIgnoreCase(next_tab))
                {
                    driver.switchTo().window(next_tab);
                    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
                    site = driver.getCurrentUrl();
                    System.out.println("Current URL:" + site); //You get the new url.
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.