# Not able to open new tab in Browser using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open new tab in selenium using below line of code

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "t"));
```

But tabs is not opening up. Can anyone tell whats wrong in this command?
Also can any one explain `"driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"))"` used in this command for ? I tried searching but not proper answers

Below complete is not working. It is opening up both gmail and stack overflow in same tab in chrome not opening up new tab

```
package TestCode;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Chrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Akash\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
        String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL+"t"); 
        driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/");
        System.out.println("Site open");
    }

}
```

Comment: Because body is common element or tag which is defined in HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use javaScripts to open new tab in chrome.

try below line of code

```
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
 js.executeScript("window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank');");
```

Refer this link :- [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812158/how-do-i-open-a-new-tab-in-chrome-using-the-actions-class)

Comment: windows.open() is implemented differently for different browser for chrome it is working fine, for chrome it is opening new tab but for firefox it is opening new browser :(

Comment: No it will be same for firefox also i have tried and it's working fine for pe..type this in firefox console window.open("https://www.google.com","_blank");

Comment: In console it opens new tab for firefox but in test script it is opening  new window

Comment: String currentUrl = getCurrentUrl();JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
   js.executeScript("window.open('"+currentUrl+"','_blank');");

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `chord` use `control`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
```

For chrome use this

first opened the tab and then hit the URL

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL+"t"); 
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/");
System.out.println("Site open");
```

Comment: This I tried, its working for Firefox, but not working in chrome browser :(

Comment: Wait i will give a solution for the chrome too

Comment: Please try this

Comment: I tried, but it is not opening new tab in chrome. It is working only in firefox. Does it have to do any thing with the chrome drivers version ? 
String KeyString = Keys.CONTROL+"t"; 
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(KeyString);

Comment: I pasted complete code in question, for your refrence

Comment: it open tab , on another url on new tab but it close previous what u want

Comment: are u want to open stakeoverflow in new tab