# Not able to click an element and redirect to new tab in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to learn selenium by testing them on different websites. In this process, I am trying to work with Flipkart website. In this, I would like to give puma is search bar and trying to click one of the resultant items. But I am not able to do that using below-mentioned code. Could anyone help in solving it?

Secondly, If we click on any item, it is redirected to new-tab. How to access the new-tab elements using the same script?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class AutomationTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/xxxx/eclipse-workspace/seleniumTesting/lib/geckoDriver/geckodriver");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.de");
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("flipkart");
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.partialLinkText("Flipkart")));
        driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Flipkart")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("._3Njdz7 [class = '_2AkmmA _29YdH8']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class = 'LM6RPg']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class = 'LM6RPg']")).sendKeys("Puma");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class = 'vh79eN']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Puma Men Black Wallet' and @class= '_1Nyybr _30XEf0']")).click();
    }

}
```

Comment: which lines are giving you trouble? To my knowledge, I believe you can go to different tabs the same way you can go to a different window: `SwitchToWindow("nameOfTab");`

Comment: Unclear what do you ask.

Comment: or [here's a link for how to switch tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java) since i'm not too familiar with Java

Comment: Question 1: During the execution of the last line in the above code I am getting the following error.

Unable to locate element: //a[@title='Puma Men Black Wallet' and @class= '_1Nyybr _30XEf0']

Question 2: If that last command works then it is redirected to the new tab. So how to access the elements from the new-tab?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the window switchTo feature.

```
String mainWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
ArrayList<String> wins = driver.getWindowHandles();
// You can use a for loop here, or get the assumed second window directly
driver.switchTo().window(wins.get(1));
// Test some things, then switch back
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(mainWindowHandle);
```

See http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#moving-between-windows-and-frames

Comment: Thank you Damian Jansen, before using your code, it should execute the last line of my code where I am getting the following error.

Unable to locate element: //a[@title='Puma Men Black Wallet' and @class= '_1Nyybr _30XEf0']. Please help me out?

Comment: your xpath got chnage that why ur getting error on last line

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to reach upto puma  and then select the option use below code

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","G:\\java programme\\SendkeysExample\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("flipkart");
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Flipkart")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.className("LM6RPg")).sendKeys("Puma");

        Robot rb = new Robot();
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        /*driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='container']/div/header/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/form/ul/li[2]/a"));
        driver.findElement(By.className("icon-add-circle"))*/;
        driver.close(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: I am able to reach puma, that is not my issue. I am not able to select an item from the results of puma search. Please help me out in figuring it.

Comment: I have updated . please look into . you can fetch desired result using above code. notify me any problem

Answer (score 0):

You will have to inspect that entire frame. I would suggest instead of customising xpaths on your own try `firebug` and `firepath` add on of `Firefox` for getting xpath of entire elements. Inspect the entire frame within which the results are getting displayed then save it in some variable like below one:

```
List<WebElements> searchResults;  
searchResults=driver.findElements(By.xpath("Your xpath"));
```

Then access elements of this list using index and then you can perform `.click()` action on the same. More on [this](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html) link for capturing xpath using `firebug` and `firepath`

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: During the execution of the last line in the above code I am getting the following error. Unable to locate element: //a[@title='Puma Men Black Wallet' and @class= '_1Nyybr _30XEf0']

--> Due to Lazy loading webelement not present in dom at the time when you are hiting click event on it. So to over come this you need to make the **webElement on view and then hit the click event.**

Please refer below code:-

```
    driver.get("https://www.google.de");
       driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("flipkart");
       driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
       WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60); 
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.partialLinkText("Flipkart")));
       driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Flipkart")).click();

       try{
       driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("._3Njdz7 [class = '_2AkmmA _29YdH8']")).click();
       }catch(Exception e){

           System.out.println("No division");
       }

       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class = 'LM6RPg']")).click();
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class = 'LM6RPg']")).sendKeys("Puma");
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class = 'vh79eN']")).click();

      // Thread.sleep(3000);

       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf( driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Puma Men Black Wallet']"))));

// getting element into view 
       ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@alt='Puma Men Black Wallet']"))); 

       Thread.sleep(2000);
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@alt='Puma Men Black Wallet']")).click();
```

Question 2: If that last command works then it is redirected to the new tab. So how to access the elements from the new-tab?

--> As suggested be @Damian Jansen add that code after last click event.

```
  String mainWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    ArrayList<String> wins = driver.getWindowHandles();

   for(String win : wins ){

       driver.switchTo().window(win);

      // other operation 

       System.out.println(driver.getTitle());   

 }
// back to old window
   driver.switchTo().window(mainWindowHandle);

   System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Hope this help you :)