# How to Open a Google Chrome with extension in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension

I have been searching for this for a while. I need to open Google Chrome with extension in selenium. The extension should be added from the Web Store and not using `.crx` file.

I have gone through many websites. Like [this](https://seleniumjava.com/2016/05/22/start-the-chrome-browser-with-extensions/) website that shows the two ways of doing it. By using the second way I'm able to launch the chrome by hard coding the path but I need to do it the first way so I can make it dynamic.

Below is the code which I have tried, using `--user-data-dir` property of chrome but it is not opening the browser with extension.

PS: I know that this can be done using `.crx` file but I need to add the extension from Chrome Store only.

Thanks in advance.

```
ChromeOptions opt1 = new ChromeOptions();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Win/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
opt1.addArguments("--user-data-dir = C:\\Sanity\\Chrome");
driver = new ChromeDriver(opt1);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Have u manual tried opening the browser with the newly created profile to see that the extension is available?

Comment: Yes, it is working manually.

Comment: Have you tried what I've put in 'hard coding' response below??

Answer (score 0):

### Using pre-configured profile

```
opt.add_argument('user-data-dir=folder')
```

where folder is the location of the chrome profile you're interested in (without any spaces before / after '=' sign preceding it - and check the location of the profile e.g. C:\Sanity\Chrome\User Data\Profile1)

### Using 'hard coding'

```
opt1.add_argument('--load-extension={folder path with manifest here}')
```

(again, no spaces)

```
opt.add_extension('{crx path here}')
```

### Mechanical way

What confues me is that you've emphasied 'from the webstore' a couple of times.  The only way I know how to download directly from webstore (i.e. after launching chrome/webdriver) is with following type of code (which makes use of Pyautogui extensively, and is less 'savvy' then your ordinary way of doing it)..

PS - I honestly think that if you just fixed your spelling/syntax with the code you're currently using, you'll be fine - some feedback in this regard would be useful btw....

```
import os, time, pyautogui
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


def activ(wd):
    global index_activ
    index_activ = False
    try:
        wd.activate()
        index_activ = True
        return index_activ
    except:
        try:
            wd.minimize()
            wd.restore()
            index_activ = True
            return index_activ
        except: pass
    index_activ = False
    return index_activ

def ext_update(section = ''):

    global w, text_temp, ys, ys2
    text_temp=  ['']
    pyautogui.click()
    def button_click(parms = ['',True]):
        #parms[0] = ID, parms[1] = click?
        ID,click = parms[0], parms[1]
        global text_temp, button
        text_temp = ''
        ID = ['omghfjlpggmjjaagoclmmobgdodcjboh'] if ID == '' else ID #default i= Browsec if no ID entered
        d.get(f'https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/{ID[0]}')
        w = WebDriverWait(d, 10)
        w.until(lambda x: x.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete")
        button = w.until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_class_name('g-c-R'))
        text_temp = button.text.lower()
        if click == True:  button.click()

    def add_remove():
        global ys, ys2, after2, handles,cl, gaw
        [cl, gaw] = [pyautogui.click,pyautogui.getActiveWindow]
        handles = d.window_handles
        activ(ys[0]), (ss, 0.5),  pr('tab'), ss(0.5), pr('space')
        while len(gwwt('')) <= len(after) : pass
        pr('escape')

    def close_extra():
        global w
        w_old = w
        w = WebDriverWait(d, 10)
        tabs_close_extra()
        activ(wd), pr('a'), activ(wd), pr('enter')
        w.until(lambda x: x.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete")
        w = w_old

    tabs_close_extra()
    before = gwwt('')
    button_click(['',False])
    if 'remove' in text_temp: return 'extension already added!'
    else: button_click()
    cc(2)
    after, ys = gwwt(''), []
    for x in after: ys = ys + [x,] if x not in before else ys
    print(add_remove())
    close_extra()
    button_click(['',False])
    print(text_temp)
    qs = 0
    qs = qs + 1 if sum(1 for x in [text_temp] if 'add' in x.lower()) > 0 else qs
    print(f'qs: {qs}')
    if section == 2: return #prevent never-ending loop (see next comment)
    if qs > 0: ext_update(section = 2) #loop back on self in case 'add extension' still present in web-stor
    return 'success'

def new_profile():
    global ev, parent, d, w, wd
    global path_core, path_exec
    global cc, ss, hk, pr, tw, gwwt

    wd = ''
    [cc, ss, hk, pr, tw, gwwt] = [pyautogui.countdown, time.sleep, pyautogui.hotkey,pyautogui.press, pyautogui.typewrite,pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle]
    path_core= os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), 'PyCharmProjects', 'Parallel')
    path_exec =  os.path.join(path_core, "chromedriver.exe")
    d = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_exec) #executable_path=path_exec)
    parent = d.current_window_handle
    w = WebDriverWait(d,5)
    #d.implicitly_wait(0.5)
    try: d.get('https://x0')
    except: pass
    start = time.time()
    while (wd == '') and (time.time() - start <=10):
        try: wd = gwwt('x0')[0]
        except: pass
    d.implicitly_wait(5)
    print('new profile complete')

def tabs_close_extra(url_karg = ''):
    # alternative method (much slower): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java
    try:
        parent = d.current_window_handle
        for h in d.window_handles:
            d.switch_to.window(h)
            if url_karg != '':
                if url_karg.lower() in d.current_url.lower(): parent = h
                else:
                    d.switch_to.window(parent)
            else: parent = h
            break
        tabs_original = len(d.window_handles)
        if tabs_original > 1:
            for h in d.window_handles:
                if h != parent:
                    d.switch_to.window(h)
                    d.close()
            d.switch_to.window(parent)
    except:
        print(f'error in tabs_close_extra ')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_profile()
    ext_update()
```

Comment: (re: Using 'hard coding':  ignore the {} surrounding folder path/crx location - you'd just put the respective locations in each case)