# How do I navigate to a newly opened tab?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a test case using Java, Selenium and Chrome Driver but I have not been able to navigate to the newly opened tab. I can see that the page opens but Selenium's focus does not move to the new tab.

I have tried a number of things: each of these points were tried on their own

```java
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

```java
element = driver.switch_to_window(element.driver.window_handles[1]);
element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"\t");
```

```java
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")), Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")),Keys.NUMPAD2).build().perform();
```

```java
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//bdi[contains(text(),'Open SQL Console')]"));
        ScriptUtils.waitFor(DELAY);
        supa.startMeasurement("40_Open_SQL_Console");
        element.click();
        System.out.println("Step 40 " );

        ScriptUtils.waitFor(DELAY);
```

````
``` java        
element = driver.switch_to_window(element.driver.window_handles[1]);
element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"\t");
````

```java
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")), Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")),Keys.NUMPAD2).build().perform();
```

I have even tried to go directly to the page but without luck.

```
driver.get ("https://mo-xxxx.mo.xxxx.corp:51043/xxxx/xxxxxa/cst/catalog/index.html?target=sqlconsole&databaseid=C119");
```

I can tell that I am on the same page because I can find an element on the current page.

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@data-xxxx-ui,
>   '__editor')]"}

The element can easily be found outside of java/selenium so I know it is there.

Comment: Have you tried anything like what's outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well, Katie.  Tried a number of other suggestions from here but deleted them as I found that they did not work.  I still get the same error message that it can not find an element on the new page (but can for the previous page).

Comment: when you debug using the method in the link from the above comment, does the tab show in the list created by `ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());`?

Comment: I am using Eclipse and have not found an easy way to debug.  New to Java, Eclipse and Selenium.  Let try to figure out that.

Comment: Ok. I would highly recommend figuring that out before you do anything else! It will make things much easier.

Comment: I wish it was 20 years ago and I was still using Cobol on the mainframe!  I did manage to figure it out using the what was outlined in your original answer Katie. I will mark it as the best answer.  Thank you.