# Switch tab then back to the original page

Tags: selenium

After clicking a row it opens a new tab and redirects you to it , what I want is after getting redirected to it , is jump back to the original tab
Original tab link is = http://localhost:82/receivechecklist.php , after clicking the row it redirects to = http://localhost:82/collection.php?wid=100000000000001

```
private static By clickFirstInvoice=By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Customer 1')]");

driver.findElement(clickFirstInvoice).click();
    Thread.sleep(500);      



new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
    driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().stream().reduce((f, s) -> s).orElse(null));
    System.out.println("Successful in switching to collection tab");
```

I want to go back to the original tab after clicking the invoice

Comment: can you try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before switching the tab you need to save the current window handle.

```
String originalTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
//perform your switch here    
driver.switchTo().window(originalTab);
```