# How to navigate to a particular tab when multiple page windows open at the same time in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, window-handles

Lets assume, I've to click on a link that open 4 more tabs. I want to shift it to 3rd tab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch tabs using Selenium WebDriver with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729265/switch-tabs-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this switchToWindow method which accept String value title of the
 tab which you need

```
public static void switchToWindow(String targetTitle) {
        WebDriver driver;
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        String origin = driver.getWindowHandle();
        for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            if (driver.getTitle().equals(targetTitle)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        driver.switchTo().window(origin);
    }
```

or you can use this method with URL

```
 public static void switchToWindow(String targetUrl) {
        WebDriver driver;
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        String origin = driver.getWindowHandle();
        for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            if (driver.getCurrentUrl().equals(targetUrl)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        driver.switchTo().window(origin);
    }
```